# how to change vscode workspace title colors

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working with multiple workspaces, I would love to be able to change the color of each sidebar menu title. Either the font, or the background color. In this example, there would be four colors. Is this possible?

[image: vscode sidebar]

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile

Answer (score 0):

the setting that seems to work is:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sideBarSectionHeader.background": "#ccff00"
  },
```

however, this controls the color for all sideBarSectionHeaders.

i believe i can modify individual headers in by changing the settings in the `.code-workspace` file. cmd + p, >, "open workspace settings (JSON)".

Comment: wait,w,you answered your own question